# MPAndroid LineChart - HOW to align XAxis labels with gridlines, display XAxis values

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart

I am new to using the MPAndroid LineChart. I have a simple code and have produced a graph as shown below:
[image]

However, on this, I want to do the following: 
1) To match the XAxis labels with the vertical grid lines, so that the grid lines also pass through the blue dots; AND

2) To show the XAxis value on the blue dots. By default, the YAxis values can be shown - I know how to do this; currently I have disabled this, and it is not shown in the picture below, but if I were to show enable them, then, they will be 0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0 and 8.0 on the 5 blue dots. What I want is to show the XAxis values instead.

Could you please suggest a way? Many thanks.

Comment: show your code. where you pass the xAxis value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. but its work for me.

```
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setTextSize(10f);
xAxis.setTextColor(Color.RED);
xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
```

For dynamic XAxis label,

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getAreaCount));
public ArrayList<String> getAreaCount() {

        ArrayList<String> label = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++)
            label.add(yourList.get(i).getTopicName());
        return label;
    }
```